# Identify movie about little boy with brain cancer who dies in the end

Tags: identify-this-movie

Okay I’ve searched for hours but I can’t find this movie. I'll list some scenes I remember.

I remember it was about a little kid who was diagnosed with brain cancer and knew he’d die soon. I remember a scene when he was lying on his bead and his face was to the pillow. his father told him "stop it" so he told him "I'm going to die anyway".

I remember him and his father (I think) going out on some journey. they asked some guy for directions. the guy made them go on a blocked road and came after them, showed them a knife and stole their money

their car was stolen also. I remember they they stopped for some guy who needed a ride. they were chatting. he told them about his wife and that she had breast cancer and the kid told him that he has brain cancer. they stopped (can't remember why), the boy and his father stepped down from the car and the guy stole the car.

I remember the kid on his father’s back. the father shouts I’m a moron and the kid replies giddy up moron.

they enter a bar. and there’s some game of a pistol duel (the guy has a pistol in his pocket, the guy in the game counts to 3 and you have to shoot him on 3) the father tried a lot but couldn't win.

…in the end the kid died. the father got back to that bar, played again and won and walked away and the bar tender asked him “don’t you want your money” but he didn't reply.

I think I saw this movie about 8 years ago or something.

Comment: Can you give anymore details, such as the location of the film, the language of it, age of actors/actresses, any direct quotes of a few lines (in addition to the ones provided)?

Comment: I googled "Saddest movie ever" but didn't find anything.

Comment: @AndrewMartin I can't remember anything more beneficial than those I wrote. They spoke English. I think it had "an oldie theme" where bars used to have short doors that swing back and forth after you enter (_I can't express what I mean_). ...I've googled many quotes leftover in my mind but no good. There's **"I am such a moron"** and **"giddy up moron"**. also **"(hey stranger,) don't you want your money?"** the bartender told the father that when he won. also **"I'm going to die anyway"**. also: **"she has the breast cancer"** when they were chatting with the guy in the car (who stole it).

Comment: @DustinDavis hahahahaha good idea that of "saddest movie ever" it is very sad XD ...yet I'm dying to find it!! it takes up a big big part in my memory

Comment: @MinaMichael: I'm finding this search extremely frustrating! Have tried all combinations of searches and went through some 27 pages of cancer movies and have got nothing. I hope someone else has more success - remember, if you can think of ANYTHING else, just add it to your post.

Comment: Yeah!! believe me I know!!! and that's why I asked here. I CAN'T FIND ANY REFERENCE TO IT ANYWHERE!!!! ...hey thanks for all your efforts so far. :D I really appreciate it!  @AndrewMartin

Comment: ... well something popped into my head but I'm not entirely sure of it. ...he was playing baseball then he fainted so they took him to the doctor and was diagnosed with brain cancer. ...I really don't know  if I've mixed that up with other movies. It's so weak a  memory. I'm not sure at all of it. >>CAUTION; MIGHT BE WRONG<< >>CAUTION; MIGHT BE WRONG<< hahahahahahaha XD

Comment: The playing baseball and fainting sound very much like "John Q" but that boy had an enlarged heart.

Comment: ...Guess we found the movie after all. thanks guys :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image: The Cactus Kid (2000) - Movie Poster]

[**The Cactus Kid** (2000)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0233402/)

Here's what the [blurb](https://www.vvs.ca/film.php?numFilm=30&title=The%20Adventures%20of%20the%20Cactus%20Kid) says:

> When **Jack discovers that his 10-year-old son Georgie is dying** he makes
>   a promise to fulfill all of his dreams before their time together runs
>   out.
>
> Georgie tells his dad that he wants to rob a bank, just like the
>   heroes in his favorite comic book "The Cactus Kid".

From the trailer page (link below) and [this](http://mainline.lightning-ent.com/movie/view/4) site:

> Jack's world collapses around him when he learns that Georgie is
>   dying of an **inoperable brain tumor**.

Scenes you might remember:

[image: The Cactus Kid (2000) - Pic 01]
[image: The Cactus Kid (2000) - Pic 02]

<sup>*~ Screenshots from [BlizzardKid](http://blizzardkid.net/category/adv-direct/kaktus_kid_zavetnoe_zhelanie_the_cactus_kid_2000_ssha_dvd-rip.print) and [The Wild Boys](http://thewildboys.flickzone1.info/viewtopic.php?id=911)*</sup>

And towards the end when Jack returns to the saloon for the shooting game:

[image: The Cactus Kid (2000) - Saloon Pic 01]
[image: The Cactus Kid (2000) - Saloon Pic 02]
[image: The Cactus Kid (2000) - Saloon Pic 03]

<sup>*~ Screenshots taken directly from the Russian video*</sup>

Watch the [trailer](http://www.traileraddict.com/cactus-kid/trailer) to confirm. Or watch the [full movie](http://www.rupirate.net/filmy/priklucheniya/28151-kaktus-kid-zavetnoe-zhelanie-the-cactus-kid-2000.html), if you don't mind sitting through a Russian dub :-)

Comment: +1: Brilliant! I'm fascinated to know - have you seen the film before, or did you find it from searching. If the latter, what did you search for? I came up totally empty!

Comment: WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOHOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOH WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOHOOOOOOOOOOOOO THAT'S IT!!!!!!!!!!!!! THAT'S THE ONE!!!!!!!!! FINALLY FINALLY FINALLY FINALLY FINALLY!!!!!!! AND YOUR ANSWER IS AWESOME WITH ALL THOSE PICTURES AND DESCRIPTIONS!!!!!!!!!!! you got yourself a 50 point bounty :D :D :D :D :D :D I REALLY REALLY CAN'T BELIEVE I FINALLY FOUND IT HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA -call the doctor; I think I've gone cuckoo- XDD

Comment: ...ofcourse we'd have to wait till "the question becomes eligible for bounty" :)

Comment: Second Andrew's question, I am in awe of your Google-fu if you managed to find it just from the description.

Comment: @Andrew - I think I kept Googling "movie with kid dying of brain tumor". Or something to that effect. But the operating word(s) was "brain tumor". There! My secret's out :-)

Comment: @Mina - Glad to pitch in. Hope you've been able to get hold of a good VHS or DVD of the movie. Also, many thanks for the (future) bounty - you're too generous :-)

Comment: @vastra360 - It's all been revealed in my last comment to Andrew :-) But you know what? The OP revealed so many important plot points without actually describing the plot (about the bank robbery). It was all out there and I guess I got lucky!

Comment: hey I googled brain tumor a lot but I didn't reach the movie. guess you were really really lucky!! ...well the bounty's all yours. It's just a little thank you. I was so so so so happy I'd found it! I searched for quite a while :D :D

Comment: @Mina - Guess I was plain lucky! Thank you once again and see you around :-)